# Import of Index content with ReadOnlyPDOMProvider

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

This articles describes how to generate and import a PDOM index.
After invoking the generation application `GeneratePDOM` I got a pdom file `/home/sadik/eclipse-2019-06/eclipse/pdomExample.pdom`. But I have problem importing the file.

The command to generate is this:

```
 java -jar plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.400.v20190515-0925.jar -application "org.eclipse.cdt.core.GeneratePDOM" -target /home/sadik/eclipse-2019-06/eclipse/pdomExample.pdom -source /home/sadik/my-plugin-runtime-2019-06/CDTTest_Local/ -id cdttest_01 -indexer org.eclipse.cdt.core.myfastIndexer
```

Note the `target` and `source` arguments.

To test the import I wrote a class that implements `IReadOnlyPDOMProvider`

```
public class MyReadOnlyPDOMProvider implements IReadOnlyPDOMProvider {

    public MyReadOnlyPDOMProvider() {
        System.out.println("PDOMProvider");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean providesFor(ICProject project) throws CoreException {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public IPDOMDescriptor[] getDescriptors(ICConfigurationDescription config) {
        final IPath fileBase = Path.fromOSString("/home/sadik/eclipse-2019-06/eclipse/");
        final IPath projectBase = Path.fromOSString("/home/sadik/my-plugin-runtime-2019-06/CDTTest_Local/");
        return new IPDOMDescriptor[] { new IPDOMDescriptor() {
            public IIndexLocationConverter getIndexLocationConverter() {
                return new URIRelativeLocationConverter(URIUtil.toURI(projectBase));
            }
            public IPath getLocation() {
                IPath path = fileBase.append("pdomExample.pdom");
                return path;
            }
        }};
    }
```

Are the paths correct? I actually don't know what location is supposed to be returned here.

I defined that class in the CDT extension point `CIndex` in my Plugin's `plugin.xml`:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.cdt.core.CIndex">
  <ReadOnlyPDOMProvider
        class="de.blub.plugin.MyReadOnlyPDOMProvider">
  </ReadOnlyPDOMProvider>
</extension>
```

I'm testing with this file (`/home/sadik/my-plugin-runtime-2019-06/CDTTest_Local/tests/indexer/usage.cc`):

```
#include <declaration.h>

int main() {
    int a = testThis();
}
```

When I right click `testThis()` and chose go to declaration, I expect to go to the function declaration in `/home/sadik/my-plugin-runtime-2019-06/CDTTest_Local/tests/indexer/declaration.h`. Both files are located in the same directory.

But what happens is that an editor is opened with an empty file. The editor even tells me the path: `/home/soezoguz/rtt-plugin-runtime-2019-06/tests/indexer/declaration.h`.

The path is missing the project name. So I guess the pdom file stores locations below the specified source directory. How can I tell the PDOMProvider to look into the correct directory for the indexed files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the trailing "/" has been ommited by `URIUtil.toURI(...)`. But in the description of `URIRealtiveLocationConverter` it says

> Note: The supplied base URI must end with a forward slash

So I create an URI instance from String and append a "/" to the String.

```
@Override
public IPDOMDescriptor[] getDescriptors(ICConfigurationDescription config) {
    final IPath fileBase = Path.fromOSString("/home/sadik/eclipse-2019-06/eclipse/");
    final IPath projectBase = config.getProjectDescription().getProject().getFullPath();
    return new IPDOMDescriptor[] { new IPDOMDescriptor() {
        public IIndexLocationConverter getIndexLocationConverter() {
            URI baseURI;
            try {
                baseURI = new URI(projectBase.toString()+"/");
                return new URIRelativeLocationConverter(baseURI);
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            baseURI = URIUtil.toURI(projectBase);
            return new URIRelativeLocationConverter(URIUtil.toURI(projectBase));
        }
        public IPath getLocation() {
            IPath path = fileBase.append("pdomExample.pdom");
            return path;
        }
    }};
}
```